# Firefox not showing fixed heading correctly with slide-out menu

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, fixed, mmenu

Here's the heading and slide-out menu I am working on: http://computerdirectoutlet.com/CDOBiz/

In Chrome and IE, the fixed menu will slide properly when the menu is expanded, but in Firefox it stays fixed over the menu. Any idea how I can fix this issue?

I'm using the mmneu jquery plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the "mm-fixed-top" class to your #header element:

```
<div class="mm-fixed-top" id="header">
```